# How do I complete my OAuth Google Login?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, oauth

My application has React and Redux running on the client side and Flask running on the server side.

I received a OAUTH token from Google on my client in the form of:

```
 Object { El: "109087143026456349612", Zi: Object, w3: Object, googleId:   
 "109087143026456349612", tokenObj: Object, tokenId:
 "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjUxNjE…", accessToken: "ya29.Ci-
 AAyPxYI7qVyKp2QTwadhiVtc9Qg…", profileObj: Object }
```

I sent this entire token object to my server via

```
 axios.post(`${local_env_url}/gconnect`, {returnData})
```

My Flask server has recognized with:

```
@app.route('/gconnect', methods=['POST'])
def gconnect():
token = request.data
```

Where do i go from here?
On the docs it says that I can verify the token by sending it to this link:
'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=%s' %(tokenid)

but it's not clear if I'm sending the entire token object or just the access token value.

Answer (score 0):

Steps are like this

1. Get google auth data after user successfully connects to your app.
2. After a user successfully signs in, send the user's ID token to your server using HTTPS.
3. Then, on the server, verify the integrity of the ID token and retrieve the user's ID from the sub claim of the ID token.

On server side you just need to send `id_token` and nothing else.

Now comes the verification of the integrity of the ID token passed to your blackened server which in your case is flask.

From server side you need to make a http request to validate the ID token to this end point -

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123
```

If the token is properly signed and valid, you will get a HTTP 200 response, where the body contains the JSON-formatted ID token claims.

You can get all the user info from the response received on server side.

To send the request to validate id_token you can use any python library to make http request or you can use google client library for python -

```
from oauth2client import client, crypt

# (Receive token by HTTPS POST)

try:
    idinfo = client.verify_id_token(token, CLIENT_ID)
    # If multiple clients access the backend server:
    if idinfo['aud'] not in [ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, IOS_CLIENT_ID, WEB_CLIENT_ID]:
        raise crypt.AppIdentityError("Unrecognized client.")
    if idinfo['iss'] not in ['accounts.google.com', 'https://accounts.google.com']:
        raise crypt.AppIdentityError("Wrong issuer.")
    if idinfo['hd'] != APPS_DOMAIN_NAME:
        raise crypt.AppIdentityError("Wrong hosted domain.")
except crypt.AppIdentityError:
    # Invalid token
userid = idinfo['sub']
```

More info [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library) - regarding how to use google client library.

Comment: Thank you, I figured this part out last night. One final part, when I verify the token, do I sent it back to the client to store in localStorage and check for it on every call to my server?

Comment: Don't store it. You can use use `gapi` to get the token.